# Web Development Work flow using git

Tags: php, javascript, git, css, project-management

I'm managing a team of 4 developers. We develop CMS based sites on a PHP / MySQL backend.

I want to improve the workflow. What i want:

[image]

- Are there any services that host a git repo and sync it automatically with the servers?
- Production server would be master branch
- Testing server would be a different branch
- we deal with many small sites and some large so we need workflow to be fast and agile
- WHAT ABOUT THE DATABASE ? lol

(if anyone wants to add to the diagram PSD file can be found here: [workflow.psd](http://andrewmclagan.com.au/workflow.psd)

Comment: Have you seen http://www.github.com?  It has hooks that you can set up to trigger pulls to your server

Comment: i second github, it also allows you to have private repo's given you purchase an upgraded account.

Comment: trigger? how? where? tell me more... lol

Comment: does your team understand simple `git` commands via terminal? it's pretty extensive once you start really getting into it.

Comment: I recommend BitBucket.org as a possible alternative to GitHub.  It provides much of the same functionality, and allows free private repos for small teams.

Comment: @Brad nice find, I might have to try these guys out, possibly save my 8 bucks a month for github ;)

Comment: ya i have heard of them, my team does not understand git at all... although i was hired as a senior developer recently and plan on changing that..

does bitbucket have automatic staging to servers?

Comment: The company behind BitBucket is Atlassian, which has a nice product called Stash, if you're in a more corporate-y environment. As far as automatic staging to servers, I believe this can be accomplished via hooks in git.

With the workflow or prod branches and dev branches look at GitFlow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd highly suggest using [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com) if you want something quick and easy to set up. It handles deployments very well. If you're looking at doing a bit more yourself (setting up the hooks and such) then another option would be [github](http://github.com).

Please do not user Master as your production branch, master should never be production. A better workflow would be to have a Staging, Development, and Production branch / environment. Please see [this guide](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/branching-best-practices.html) about branching on Beanstalk's guides, it's pretty insightful.

As for keeping track of databases, if your framework / cms doesn't support database migration I'd highly suggest developing some form of migration / database version control in-house. You can also check out a framework like [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/), which has migration built in. A nice little database version control system I found while poking around : [dbv.php](http://dbv.vizuina.com/).

Comment: So it seems that its best to develop in the main branch and have separate branches for staging and production. +1 for that tip, previously i have worked main branch production, subbranches for development and staging

Comment: No problem :) Yeah, Master should ALWAYS be used as the main development. It's in the same sense as Trunk is the main development branch for SVN.